# Probability problem with or/and (meaning of "neither").

Tags: probability, logic, definition, logic-translation

> In a certain Algebra 2 class of 28 students, 5 of them play basketball and 21 of them play baseball. There are 5 students who play neither sport. What is the probability that a student chosen randomly from the class plays both basketball and baseball?

Does 'neither' mean 'not basketball AND not baseball'? Or 'not basketball OR not baseball'?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! When you post questions here, you must mention something you have tried rather than just posting the question. Otherwise people will downvote to close the post.

Comment: This is more a problem about logic translation than about probability.

Answer (score 4):

The word *neither* means

> not the one nor the other of two people or things; not either.

So, when the question says that the students play neither sport, it means they do not play baseball and does not play basketball.

Answer (score 1):

*A student plays neither basketball nor baseball* is an unambiguous way of saying that said student does not play basketball and does not play baseball.

Answer (score 0):

5 students do not play at all.  Therefore 23 students play  at least one sport.  Add numbers for both sport and get 26, so 3 students play both.  So probability of student chosen at random plays both is 3/28.